# Snap related error in dmesg, snapd-desktop-i[1403]: segfault at 0, error 4 in libglib-2.0

Tags: snap

I'm using Ubuntu mate 22.04 and default snap app of Firefox and my Bluetooth is turned off and following errors (they were in red colour in terminal) came up after using `dmesg` command:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000


snapd-desktop-i[1403]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fe679ea8364 sp 00007ffc1f2e83f8 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7fe679e7e000+9a000]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seeing these as well. If anyone has any information, I've interested.

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 22.04 
Jul 30 14:14:22 oliver snapd-desktop-i[1766]: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
Jul 30 14:14:22 oliver kernel: [    8.685778] snapd-desktop-i[1766]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f5dd5fb2364 sp 00007ffddb817c68 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f5dd5f88000+9a000]

Comment: Seems a bug (hence, out of scope on AU) on snapd-desktop-integration you should report [here](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/issues)